# Working with keys in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: r, pandas, key

In R, Setkey can be used to work with keys and i.e. my data table gets sorted automatically when using aggregation functions. The R-Command I use is:
setkey(myData, “Customer”)

Does Python/Pandas also work with keys and Is there an equivalent for the R-Command?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should probably post an example for those who are not familiar with R. Otherwise, it's hard to understand what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

R's data.table setkey() function, as far as I know, doesn't have a direct equivalent in Python. However, there are a few functions that replace this functionality. Note the `inplace` parameter for these functions. If you don't specify `inplace=True`, the underlying data is not changed unless you explicitly assign (e.g., `df = df.sort_values('a')

You can use the [sort_values()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) function to sort your data on one or more columns.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,2,1,2,2,2],
                   'b': [1,1,0,2,4,1,5],
                   'c': [3,4,5,2,6,1,7]})

>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  1  3
1  1  1  4
2  2  0  5
3  1  2  2
4  2  4  6
5  2  1  1
6  2  5  7

>>> df.sort_values(['a', 'b'])
   a  b  c
0  1  1  3
1  1  1  4
3  1  2  2
2  2  0  5
5  2  1  1
4  2  4  6
6  2  5  7
```

If you are performing aggregation on a column or series of columns, you can use the [groupby()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function. This is similar to the `by` operator in R's data.table.

```
>>> df.groupby(['a', 'b'])['c'].max()
a  b
1  1    4
   2    2
2  0    5
   1    1
   4    6
   5    7
```

You can also set the index to be one or more columns using the [set_index()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) function.

```
>>> df.set_index('a')
   b  c
a      
1  1  3
1  1  4
2  0  5
1  2  2
2  4  6
2  1  1
2  5  7

# once the index is set, you reference rows on the new index.

df.set_index('a', inplace=True)
df.ix[1]
>>> df.ix[1]
   b  c
a      
1  1  3
1  1  4
1  2  2
```